# How to resume a git bisect

Tags: git, git-bisect, bisect

Suppose that I'm going through a git bisect, and after running a `git bisect bad` command, my git bisect gets interrupted like so:

```
$ git bisect bad
Bisecting: 0 revisions left to test after this (roughly 1 step)
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    app/app.iml
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

I can simply eliminate this file by running:

```
git checkout -- app/app.iml
```

which will make my git state clean again.. but I'm not sure how to proceed thereafter (ie to let git bisect continue bisecting).. I believe I've done a `git bisect bad` before and it kind of skipped a step or did something i didn't expect it to. I simply want to resume my git bisect operation.. how to do that?

Comment: I would guess that the `git bisect bad` didn't apply so you just have to run it again. In case you're not sure, take a look at `git bisect log` (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect#_bisect_log_and_bisect_replay)

Answer (score 12):

The last thing `git bisect good` or `git bisect bad` does is run `git checkout` on the next commit to test.  It's this `git checkout` itself that failed.

The revision that `git bisect` was attempting to `git checkout` is stored in the special ref `BISECT_EXPECTED_REV`.  You can clean up whatever failed and run `git checkout BISECT_EXPECTED_REV` to check it out.  You will need to resume any automated or manual testing at this point.

Answer (score 2):

You can always write `git bisect log` which will output all the bisect operations done so far.

If you save this output, you can later replay it using `git bisect replay <logfile>`